Why does Dart FFI fail to DynamicLibrary.open a DLL once it has dependencies (error code 126)
I'm using Dart FFI for the first time, and I've started writing a small C++ library that I want to access using dart:ffi.
I'm using the Visual Studio build tools, as I'm only targeting Windows, and my project is set up like this:
- my_flutter_project_root
  - lib
  - (etc.)
  - native
    - my_native_solution
      - include
        - [all the headers from dart-sdk/include]
      - libs
        - dart.lib (from dart-sdk/bin)
      - my_source_code
      - x64
        - Release
          - my_native_library.dll
      - my_native_solution.sln

If I remove the dependency on dart.lib, I'm able to load
ffi.DynamicLibrary.open(path.join(Directory.current.path, 'native', 'my_native_solution', 'x64', 'Release', 'my_native_library.dll'))
just fine, however, once I add the dependency, the code fails with
════════ Exception caught by scheduler library ═════════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown during a scheduler callback:
Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'my_native_library.dll': The specified module 
could not be found.
(error code: 126)

From the answers I found I can tell that this is apparently caused by the loader not being able to locate the library's dependencies, but I couldn't figure out how to resolve this issue.
I'd appreciate help on how I need to structure my project in order to avoid this.

@drescherjm Whoops, that's just my library in question, made an edit to correct it

Try putting the dependencies into a folder in the windows path

@RichardHeap sadly, no change
